# How an actor identify itself?

Tags: f#, akka.net

I have the following code which spawns many worker actors. The worker actor will need to send a message to the task dispatcher to ask for more tasks if idle. How the actor identify itself?

```
let system = System.create "System" <| Configuration.load ()

let taskDispatcher (mailbox: Actor<_>) = .... // Send message to processor to assign tasks

let processor (mailbox: Actor<MyTask>) =
    let rec loop () = actor {
        // ... task done. send message to the dispatcher for a new task
        return! loop ()
    }
    loop ()

let processors = [
    spawn system "System" processor
    spawn system "System" processor
    spawn system "System" processor
    // .... many more
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameter you're calling `mailbox` (an `Actor<'t>`) has a property called `Self` that gives you an `IActorRef` to the current actor.  You can also get the `IActorRef` of the actor that sent the message you're currently processing by calling the `Sender` method on the mailbox.  You can use these properties to reply to the sender, send messages to yourself, or to send your own actor reference to another actor so they can send you messages.

One thing to note is that you should be giving each actor a unique name when you call `spawn`.  You can't have two actors with the same name in the same actor system.

Here's a simple example of the message loop using these properties:

```
type Msg = HelloFrom of IActorRef

spawn system "my-actor"
<| fun mailbox ->
    let rec loop () = 
        actor {
            let! message = mailbox.Receive()
            mailbox.Sender() <! HelloFrom mailbox.Self
            return! loop ()
        }
    loop ()
```